# Audit-Error when accessing remote computer with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote a powershell script that tests if a prozess on a remote computer is running and then does actions on my local comperter depending on the prozess state on the remote computer.

The scripts works fine and i get the results i want. BUT when checking the Security-Event-Log on the remote computer i get an Audit-Failure-Entry. In this Entry it looks like the remote computer try to log on with an account on my local computer

```bsh
$Prozess = "<Prozessname>'"                           
$Server = "<RemoteServer>"                         
$Password = "<Password>"                            
$Username = "<UserOnRemoteServer>"                       

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString
$ProzessListe = gwmi win32_Process -ComputerName $Server -Authentication 3 -Credential $MySecureCreds -Impersonation Impersonate -Filter "name = $Prozess"
```

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byeZx.jpg)

Edit:
After changening the Line for $Prozessliste to

```
$ProzessListe = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $MySecureCreds  -Authentication Negotiate -ScriptBlock{gwmi win32_Process -Filter "name = $($args[0])"} -ArgumentList $Prozess
```

the Audit-Error is gone.

Comment: could you share a picture of the event or the message?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I added a screenshot of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're authenticating with NTLM it will attempt authentication anonymously before attempting with credentials. This initial anonymous attempt failure might be what you are seeing.

Comment: how do i have to change the Authentication to prevent this error?

Comment: If it's NTLM then you don't. It's just the way the authentication works. It's benign.